# Kibana - Add control number field - not as "Range Slider"

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk

I have a number field in my index that states the job id and I want to filter by a specific job. So I want to create a 'control' to choose one job id from an options list. But whenever I choose the field the only option is "Range slider". How can I change that?

[image]

Comment: Probably because `job_id` is mapped as a number and not a keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most probably because `job_id` is mapped as a number and not a keyword.

So you can either change your mapping and reindex your data or create a `keyword` sub-field, update your index in place and then use the `...job_id.keyword` field so create your control. An example of the second option can be found [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73399049/elasticsearch-how-can-i-convert-long-data-type-into-keyword-or-text/73399339#73399339)

Comment: How do I "change my mapping and reindex your data"?

Comment: How do I set the type keyword?

Comment: Please see the second link I gave, it shows you how to do it

Comment: I don't want to add another field because I get millions of metrics per day and I want it to be as thin as possible.

Comment: Ok, then you need to go for the first option, i.e. you need to change your index mapping to map `job_id` as keyword instead of a numeric type and reindex your data into the new index. [This link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#updating-field-mappings) provides the exact steps to carry out to achieve this.