# Search results in Elasticsearch do not match expectations

Tags: elasticsearch

The real data type of number_2 is float, and this is my search criteria:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50,
  "timeout": "60s",
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {
            "boost": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "item": {
                    "value": "project_online_1.1002",
                    "boost": 1
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "number_2": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is part of the result of the query :

```
{
    "_index": "blue_0",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "project_online_1_1002_20164279",
    "_score": null,
    "_source": {
        "project": "project_online_1",
        "item": "project_online_1.1002",
        "text_0": "emp3",
        "bool_0": false,
        "number_2": 20164279,
        "bool_1": false,
        "bool_2": false,
        "text_4": "3xs7vovx",
        "bool_3": false,
        "number_4": 0,
        "datetime_6": "2023-08-09T10:15:30.281Z",
        "datetime_7": "2023-08-09T10:16:06.751Z",
        "number_8": null,
        "text_8": "KeDUkyqM0OjJ7ZlIdDNMe9.png",
        "number_12": 2026,
        "text_18": null,
        "number_30": 188,
        "text_22": "4f4becdd-88b1-4b60-ad44-de90510fcb54",
        "text_1": "free",
        "text_2": null,
        "bool_4": true,
        "bool_5": false,
        "bool_6": false,
        "bool_7": false,
        "bool_8": true,
        "number_31": null,
        "text_23": null
    },
    "sort": [
        20164280
    ]
},
{
    "_index": "blue_0",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "project_online_1_1002_20164278",
    "_score": null,
    "_source": {
        "project": "project_online_1",
        "item": "project_online_1.1002",
        "text_0": "0809_app_setting_test_test_2",
        "bool_0": false,
        "number_2": 20164278,
        "bool_1": false,
        "bool_2": false,
        "text_4": "rotcqizm",
        "bool_3": false,
        "number_4": 0,
        "datetime_6": "2023-08-09T10:15:15.459Z",
        "datetime_7": "2023-08-10T10:04:06.839Z",
        "number_8": null,
        "text_8": "vMx5AqClFbKPc0Nov0PHV.png",
        "number_12": 2026,
        "text_18": null,
        "number_30": 227,
        "text_22": "277a7ae7-9cd3-40a4-82f8-fda0ea500742",
        "text_1": "free",
        "text_2": null,
        "bool_4": true,
        "bool_5": false,
        "bool_6": false,
        "bool_7": false,
        "bool_8": true,
        "number_31": null,
        "text_23": null
    },
    "sort": [
        20164278
    ]
}
```

As you can see, when number_2 equals 20164279, the value of the "sort" field in the result is 20164280,which leads to confusion in sorting. Can someone help me explain the reason?

I tried to delete the entire index and reconstruct the data, but to no avail

Comment: What is the real data type of `number_2`? Can you share what you get from `GET blue_0/_mapping/field/number_2` ?

Comment: The real data type of number_2 is float, and definition of this field is right, but the search result  are confusing.

Comment: The problem has been described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77327187/4604579), float doesn't have exact precision for numbers coming after 16,777,216 and 20,164,279 is higher than that

Comment: Well!,maybe this is where my problem lies, but I still have one question, I tried to construct the same value on other machines without any problems, but this problem has been happening on this machine. Can you help me answer why?

Comment: Can you describe the machine on which it doesn't work and the ones on which that works?

Comment: Using jdk8 and Elasticsearch 7.17.8 on my macbook air is normal, but using jdk8 and Elasticsearch 7.10.1 on a Debian server may result in incorrect results. Is it related to the version of Elasticsearch?

Comment: Why do you say "may result" for Debian? Do you get deterministically wrong results all the time, or is it swinging from good to bad results without reason?

Comment: Sorry, it may be that my description was not clear enough, some data in Debian is not in the correct order, and most of the data is normal. The issue of incorrect results only occurs in Debian.

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing precision loss. According to [elasticsearch documentation on numbers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/number.html), float has 7.22 significant digits. Since your number "20164279" has 8 digits, the last digit is not guaranteed to be the one, you wrote into the index.
If your number is a floating point number use double for more precision.
If it is not a floating point number, use integer or long.

Comment: So my data has already used the float type, how should I fix the data without deleting the mapping? I tried adding the ['numeric_type: double'](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/sort-search-results.html#_sorting_numeric_fields)  parameter to the query criteria, but I didn't get the correct result.

Comment: @freedom You can modify the mapping to add a `double` sub-field to the `number_2` field and then run `_update_by_query` on your index, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73399049/elasticsearch-how-can-i-convert-long-data-type-into-keyword-or-text/73399339#73399339

Comment: @freedom But if your numbers are not floating point (they are not in the example you gave), I'd use long instead of double

Comment: @Val I completely agree with your opinion, but in my program, I need to use this field to represent integers and decimals, so I have decided to use the double type, and I am trying to fix it using the reindex API.

Comment: Ok in that case using double makes sense